# Flutter: how to make a list that always scrolls to the bottom?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make a list that is basically a log screen. That said, I need the list to keep scrolling to bottom all the time.

How this can be done?

Comment: add `reverse: true` https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html (and add the items in reversed order)

Comment: I tried that but is almost impossible to add the itens in reverse order, since the "ReplaySubject" has no method for this =(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could make this work by using a `Timer` but probably should have a better way to do this.
My workaround was:

1. Define a `ScrollController()` and attach it to the listView:

```
ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: _logLines.values.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => _getLogLine(index),
    )
```

2. Override your page `initState` method and set a Timer inside it like:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
      super.initState();
      Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 100), (timer) {
        if (mounted) {
            _scrollToBottom();
        } else {
          timer.cancel();
        }
      });
    }
```

3. Define a method `_scrollToBottom()` that calls:

   `_scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);`

Comment: Why you need a timer ? you can use .jumpTo only when there is a new log ..

Comment: My position object is always null, I have attached it to a singleChildScorllview. Can you help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: The answer for M. Leonhard is cleaner. You can avoid dealing with stateful widgets, timers, remembering to cancel them, and so on.

Answer (score 30):

Set `reverse: true` on the [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.html) widget and reverse the children list.

```dart
ListView(
  // Start scrolled to the bottom by default and stay there.
  reverse: true,
  children: widget.children.reversed.toList(growable: false),
),
```

If you have a very long list and reversing is expensive, you can reverse the index rather than the whole list using ListView.builder

```dart
ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    itemCount: items.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      final reversedIndex = items.length - 1 - index;
      final item = items[reversedIndex];
      return MyWidget(item);
    }
)
```

I got this from Günter's comment above.  Thanks!

Comment: Added an edit on how you can use a `ListView.builder` to accomplish the same

Comment: Thanks a ton! For me the list was very long and my list was kind of a sticky list with an header where I had used a map to get the header from the key and the list items from the values (which are a list). This solution worked best for me. FYI, SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  controller1.animateTo(
    controller1.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 10),
    curve: Curves.easeOut,);
  });
} didn't work for me. It just scrolled my list halfway

Comment: This will reverse the order of the items in the list, putting the last item first and the first item last. It will not actually show the bottom. It will show the top while switching the items around.

Answer (score 12):

I found `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` extremely useful, especially in situations like this where you need some post build processing. In this case it solved the issue as follows:

1. Define the ScrollController

```dart
final ScrollController _sc = ScrollController();
```

2. In the ListView builder add the statement:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => {_sc.jumpTo(_sc.position.maxScrollExtent)});
```

3. Add the controller to ListView parameters:

```dart
controller: _sc,
```

I was also building a logger viewer. Works like a charm.

Comment: To me, I think this should be marked as the correct answer. Whenever list is built it shows the bottom of the list. No timer needed.

Comment: Thanks. I always look for the fewest moving parts to keep Murphy at bay.

Comment: I think this is the most efficient method

Comment: Yes, this works just fine... This should be the accepted answer.... Pretty neat and clear

Comment: excellent answer, thanks

Comment: What a perfect answer. Cheers!!!!!